# how to press a button one , and then the second one stops?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I make presses button  in the Second one and then stops and then pressed again in the Second one and then stops

But pressure All buttons in second one

I want to press a button 1, and then the second one stops
and then press the button 2, then the second one stops
and then press the button 3, then the second one stops 
and then press the button 4, then the second one stops 
and then press the button 5, then the second one stops

How ??!!

i try this

**jquery**

```
<script>
function fs (){
  alert("hello");
  }

setTimeout(function() {
$("#a tr").each(function(){
   $(this).find("input[type=submit]").click();
    });
       }, 1000);

</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<table id='a' border='2'>
<tr>
<td>1 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs ()'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>2 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs ()' /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>3 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs ()'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs ()'/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>5 = <input type='submit' value='send' onclick=' fs ()' /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

**But pressure All buttons in second one**  >_<

Comment: Reading your question feel's like puzzle...

Comment: You html is not valid for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $("#a tr :submit").each(function(i ,v){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(v).click();
        }, (i + 1)* 1000);
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mw4be/1/)

Comment: Arun P Johny
Thank you, man ^_^

Thank you very much